# Is it possible to use both ordinary mysql and PDO at the same time?

Tags: php, pdo

This site I'm working on uses ordinary mysql_query()-stuff. And I want to use the PDO-extension.
The problem I'm experiencing is that the PDO class is not found when I try to add the PDO-connection at the very top of the site together with the mysql-connection.

This is kind of wierd since if i start a blank document, anywhere on my server, it works whitout any problems.
If I create a new document in the root of my public folder, or inside my pages/ -directory and then go directly to that document - everything works greate.

I also created a new folder for a subdomain and basically created a new site using PDO without any problems.

Does anyone know what could cause this behaviour?
Is it because I'm using ordinary mysql-connection?

I checked phpinfo(); within the site, and it wasn't listed. (mysite.com/?page=phpinfo)
but when I check phpinfo inside any direct document, it is listed... (mysite.com/pages/phpinfo.php)
*both url's above refers to the same document*

Comment: Sounds like the site/server configuration makes it run on a different version of PHP. No, there's no problem with mysql + PDO.

Comment: okay.Do you know how I can check that? btw. I added a short info at the bottom of my post...

Comment: For a start, compare all details of `phpinfo()` for any differences...

Comment: I did compare them and everything seems to be the same, except that one of them, the one where i access the document directly, loads PDO extension and the other one doesn't obviously.

Comment: Why do you want to use the mysql_ and PDO at the same time? Why not just use PDO?

Comment: This is an existing site that is already programmed with mysql_. The new stuff I'm adding, I want to use PDO... Then, when I have the time, I'll rewrite the code bit by bit...